# Creating a matrix in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix, 3d

Imagine that I have two observed variables, interest and M2, both with length 1000.

I am trying to apply a function taking each observation of interest and M2 to generate a matrix of values called PCoCo. The matrix will have a 1000x1000 length.

The purpose is to generate a 3D surface plot with x = interest, y = M2, z = PCoCo.

I have the following code:

```
 #Creating a matrix from 2 variables; interest, M2, and a function CoCo.Price.

 interest = seq(0,0.1, length = 1000)
 M2 = seq(0,10, length = 1000)

#PCoCo = price of the coco, should be a matrix

 PCoCo = matrix(nrow=length(interest), ncol=(M2))

 f = function(interest, M2){

for(i in 1:length(interest)){

for(j in 1:length(M2)){

  PCoCo[j,i] = CoCo.Price(C.p, c.r, m, N, q, interest[i], S, S.Trigger, 
  sigma, M2[j])
  }
 } 
}

z = outer(interest, M2, f)
```

I used to get the following error before assigning PCoCo as a matrix before running f:

```
Error in PCoCo[j, i] <- matrix(CoCo.Price(C.p, c.r, m, N, q, interest[i],  : 
incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

Now, I do not, however R is taking ages to compute the matrix.

I have tried reducing the dimensions to 100x100 but it is still taking very long.

The issue might be with the CoCo.Price function as it is about a 100 line function, which also has some foor loops in it.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: I can see at least two problems with the instruction throwing the error. Function `matrix` should have at least one of the arguments `nrow` or `ncol`. And `matrix` already returns a matrix, you're assigning it to ONE element of `PCoCo`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas 

Hi and thanks for the tip. I have changed the code now. First of all, I have assigned PCoCo = matrix(nrow = length(interest), ncol = length(M2)).

I have also removed the matrix from the PCoCo[i,j] part. 

Now my issue is that it is taking ages to compute...